# Basic openSUSE Grub entry for Fedora on another disk

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

I have 2 hard disks, one SSD (`/dev/nvme0n1`) and one HDD (`/dev/sda`).

On sda I have: `/dev/sda1` which is btrfs, 250GB big and has openSUSE Tumbleweed on it, and `/dev/sda2` which is swap.

On the other disk, I have Fedora with the following order (once correctly booted):

- `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, fat32, ESP, UEFI partition mounted on `/boot/efi`
- `/dev/nvme0n1p2`, ext4, 1GB small boot partition mounted on `/boot`
- `/dev/nvme0n1p3`, swap
- `/dev/nvme0n1p4`, btrfs, 250GB big and has Fedora on it.

I need your help to fix the following entry that I created in my `grub.cfg` on Tumbleweed (I have to do it manually because my Grub yields an error about missing `.mod` files when I try to run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, which is also a problem I need to adress but maybe in another topic):

```
menuentry 'Fedora' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-8a9a8f64-1ce9-45d2-b9dc-ba4cd756134e' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd1,gpt2'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e130ac5a-55fb-4620-a63b-41184c9c680f
    linux    /vmlinuz-6.5.7-200.fc38.x86_64 root=UUID=e130ac5a-55fb-4620-a63b-41184c9c680f resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/81a52966-11cf-4204-8e0b-4568796b2e5b quiet
    echo 'Loading Linux ...'
    initrd   /initramfs-6.5.7-200.fc38.x86_64.img
    echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
}
```

Here's the relevant part of `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="BAFC-2878" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="5dff6717-47a9-4681-a12d-2ce66cc67b4b"

/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="e130ac5a-55fb-4620-a63b-41184c9c680f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e317be0c-9d57-4652-8b1d-012695fedc14"

/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="81a52966-11cf-4204-8e0b-4568796b2e5b" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="swap" PARTUUID="85d0f9d4-ee34-49f7-899d-59aea5b8002e"

/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="fedora_localhost-live" UUID="8a9a8f64-1ce9-45d2-b9dc-ba4cd756134e" UUID_SUB="5fe247b5-98e2-43f2-af8e-de9f1624016f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="e2a9ada3-4e91-4441-b7d2-8a49048b1573"
```

Can any Grub-expert tell me if my entry is right? Unfortunately I think it's not, because when I try to boot from it:

1. I get an error about `zfs.mod` not being found, but...
2. ...after a few seconds it starts to boot. However, at the `initr` stage, I get this error:

   Failed to switch root: Specified switch root path '/sysroot' does not seem to be an OS tree. os-release file is missing.

I tried a few solutions I found online, that explained how to mount this `/sysroot` anyway, but the error didn't go away and I couldn't boot.

So please, if you know Grub entries, help!

Comment: Are you using zfs? Then you may need `insmod zfs` like your `insmod fat` entry. Do not know zfs, but you show three UUIDs, so is that zfs pools? And which is which? You should list your zfs, so those who know it can answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Can you however tell me the command to list my zfs?

Comment: I only have used ext4 which is standard with Ubuntu. I have not used OpenSUSE. If you are using zfs, I would expect you to know how to list, review & repair that file systems. Some info here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2491426  & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/ZFS  & https://linux.slashdot.org/story/20/01/19/0059251/what-linus-torvalds-gets-wrong-about-zfs#comments